# Showing Lipschitz continuity for a particular distance function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

My friend and I have been working on trying to prove this inequality for a while. However, I think there is some trick we are just not seeing.

Suppose $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, whose complement has finite measure, and let

$$ \delta(x)=d(x,F)=\inf \{ |x - y| : y \in F \}.$$

Prove $$ \mid \delta(x) - \delta(y)| \le |x-y|.$$

Answer (score 14):

Let $x,y\in \Bbb R$.

For all $z\in F$ we have
$$\delta(x)\leq |x-z|\leq |x-y|+|y-z|,$$
hence $\delta(x)-|x-y|\leq |y-z|$ for all $z\in F$.
It follows that
$$
\delta(x)-|x-y|\leq \inf_{z\in F}|y-z|=\delta(y).
$$

Now we get $\delta(x)-\delta(y)\leq |x-y|$.

By the same argument we can show  also that $\delta(y)-\delta(x)\leq |x-y|$, so $|\delta(x)-\delta(y)|\leq |x-y|$.

**Remark:** The hypotheses on $F$ are unnecessary, the result holds for arbitrary subsets $F$, and an essentially identical argument shows that the result holds for arbitrary subsets $F$ of metric spaces $(X,d)$, where $\delta$ is defined by $\delta(x) = \inf\{d(x,y) : y\in F\}$.

Comment: It seems you didn't even have to assume that $F$ is closed, or am I mistaken?

Comment: It is also true without this hypothesis (closed).

Comment: Since the question was tagged with metric spaces, let me add that we have only used that $(x,y)\mapsto |x-y|$ is a metric in euclidean space so this argument also works for the distance function of a set in an arbitrary metric space.